# How can i change the name order in the admin?

Tags: users, username

When i go to wp-admin/users.php, in the second column i can see the users full name, however, its not in the right order. In Hungary, we use a different name order: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_names

So i need to change the name from "First name - Last name" to "Last name - First name"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alter the default Name column, but what you can do is hide it and create your own custom column.

First, we add the action and filter on `admin_init` that will add and manage our new column:

```
function wpa66544_user_custom_column_init(){
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'wpa66544_user_add_column' );    
    add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'wpa66544_user_manage_column', 100, 3 );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpa66544_user_custom_column_init' );
```

Next, the function hooked to our filter above which removes the default name column and adds our own custom column:

```
function wpa66544_user_add_column( $columns ) {
    // hide the default name column
    unset( $columns['name'] );

    // add our custom name column
    $columns['custom_name']  = 'Name';        
    return $columns;
}
```

Last, the function hooked to the action in the first step which outputs the value of the column for each user:

```
function wpa66544_user_manage_column( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    $last_first = '';
    if ( 'custom_name' == $column_name ):
        $first_name = get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $user_id );
        $last_name = get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $user_id );
        $last_first = $last_name . ' ' . $first_name;
    endif;
    return $last_first;
}
```

The one thing missing here is that the column is not sortable. I haven't quite figured out how to do this, though I know the possible method is via the `pre_user_query` action. It seems the SQL has to be modified directly, as the normal means of making a column sortable won't work in this instance. first/last name are user meta, and you can't order by user meta within this context of a user query.

It also seems that the default Name column is also not sortable anyway, clicking the Name header just does the same thing as clicking the username header- sorts by username, so I suppose you're not really losing any functionality here!